# Shutting Down Vagrant Box

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

Is there any difference between typing `vagrant halt` and right clicking on the box in Virtual Box and selecting **close>power off**

Also on my Windows 7 machine running Vagrant on VirtualBox should I shut down Vagrant using `vagrant halt` before putting the machine to sleep or hibernating or does it make any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no difference. You can see the source for the halt command [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/commands/halt/command.rb).

There's no particular need to shut them down or suspend them when your host sleeps, as far as I know (although I mostly use Vagrant on a Mac), but sometimes there can be peculiar behaviour. For example:

1. Have a Vagrant box running (in my case Ubuntu 14.04)
2. Close the host computer. (goes to sleep)
3. time passes...
4. Open the host computer.
5. Log on to Vagrant box and observe system time. It is off (behind) by the amount of time the host was asleep.

I first noticed this because AWS rejects commands that haven't been signed within the last 5 minutes. It's easy to fix with a VBox option in the Vagrantfile to set the NTP update threshold to a lower value (like 10 seconds):

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize [ :guestproperty, :set, :id, "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold", 10000 ]
end
```

Unlike halt/suspend, you should use always use `vagrant destroy` in lieu of VBox to delete a VM, in order to give the provisioners an opportunity to clean up.